# R - Concurrent Programming

Tags: r

Is it possible to do concurrent programming in R

For example, running 2 functions with while(TRUE) loops concurrently.

Comment: What are you trying to do, this sounds like a fairly weird way of using R.

Comment: Why is this weird? The OP has not stated why he wants to do this, but I can think of a few good reasons.

Comment: 1. Use `repeat` instead of `while(TRUE)`. 2. There are many ways of doing parallel computations in R.  See the HPC task view. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: There are some nice suggestions here, but everything is about 2 years old.  I am hoping that my comment might bring this to the forefront and we can hear more updates.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 8):

The snow, Rmpi, and pvm packages have supported this for almost a decade, initially across computers and also on a multi-cpu or multi-core machine.

The multicore package added a the ability to do this on multi-core machines.

Since R 2.14.0, the parallel package has bundled parts of snow and multicore in the basic R distribution.  This may be your best starting point now.

A few parts of R itself also use multi-threaded programming, but that approach is limited due to some architectural constraints that are unlikely to be lifted.

We wrote a [survey paper on parallel programming with R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01/) a few years ago which is still relevant.

Comment: https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcN_DpYBzKso&ei=TAGvUoudB4KGrAemiIGACw&usg=AFQjCNFHSCJL1RjuO-F7kj8qTL5eKoWkeQ&sig2=r7lbvYm4M3Qyvk3LYmVLew&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bmk

Answer (score 5):

Yes as of version 2.14.0 the parallel package is included so you can run things on different threads for one instance of R. See: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html